# ASP.NET Web.config authentication/authorization settings

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, web-config, authorization, windows-authentication

I'm trying to configure the IIS Authentication settings from my MVC5 project in the Web.config file.

Here's what I have.  I want Windows Authentication enabled and Anonymous Authentication disabled.

[image]

But after publishing my package in IIS, the settings are this.

[image]

What do I need to do to also set the Anonymous Authentication to **Disabled** in the Web.config?
Isn't that what `<deny users "?"/>` is supposed to be doing?

Comment: @mavora, <deny users "?"/> is using  to allow only authenticated users

Comment: praguan - isn't that the same thing as disallowing anonymous?

Comment: @mavora, deny = * means deny everyone;     
deny = ? means deny unauthenticated users

Comment: Thanks.  I was assuming that was what changed the Anonymous Authentication setting.

Answer (score 7):

Here we go step by step:

1. Open Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager:

   - If you are using Windows Server 2012 or Windows Server 2012 R2:
   - On the taskbar, click Server Manager, click Tools, and then click
     Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.
   - If you are using Windows 8 or Windows 8.1:
   - Hold down the Windows key, press the letter X, and then click Control
     Panel. Click Administrative Tools, and then double-click Internet
     Information Services (IIS) Manager.
   - If you are using Windows Server 2008 or Windows Server 2008 R2:
   - On the taskbar, click Start, point to Administrative Tools, and then
     click

     **Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.**
   - If you are using Windows Vista or Windows 7:
   - On the taskbar, click Start, and then click Control Panel.
   - Double-click Administrative Tools, and then double-click Internet
     Information Services (IIS) Manager.

     2. In the Connections pane, expand the server name, expand Sites, and go to the level in the hierarchy pane that you want to configure, and then click the Web site or Web application.
     3. Scroll to the Security section in the Home pane, and then double-click Authentication.
        4.In the Authentication pane, select Anonymous Authentication, and then click Disable in the Actions pane.

Or you can disable by config file:

```
<location path="Contoso">
   <system.webServer>
      <security>
         <authentication>
            <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />   <!--This line you need-->
            <basicAuthentication enabled="true" defaultLogonDomain="Contoso" />
            <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
          </authentication>
      </security>
   </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Deny Anonymous user to access entire website:

```
   <authorization>
    <deny users="?" ></deny>    
    </authorization>
```

Hope it helps;)

Comment: I see where you got these settings.
https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication
They do not work and bring up an error in IIS, and I'm excluding the location path and basicaauthentication parts.

Comment: @try to use that script where I showed to disable by config file ;)

Comment: Sorry, but your first set of code errors out similar to this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28419304/programmatically-enable-or-disable-anonymous-authentication-in-iis

Your second set of code is what I already have.

Comment: I concur with @Madvora, the [first set of code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/security/authentication/) doesn't seem to work for me either. Do you have a example of a full web.config with that implemented?

Answer (score -2):

Right click on Anonymous Authentication and click disable

Comment: Yeah I know how to change the settings in IIS, I'm trying to set this in the Web.config and wondering why my settings there don't translate.

Comment: It only works when you run locally(through VS),but for IIS, you need to disable it.